# Loading delay extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, panel, loading, mask

I have a panel within which I have two more panels. When you click on panel1 then information in panel2 is loaded. Since the information is quite huge there is some delay when its being loaded. During this interim period I wish to add a loading mask which intimates the user that its getting loaded.

For the same I have done this:

```
var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getCmp('eventsPanel'), {
        msg:"Please wait..."
});
myMask.show(); 
// eventsPanel is the main panel under which panel1 and panel2 lie.
// This code is in the selectionchange listener of panel1 whose code
// is inside the main eventsPanel code.
```

However, nothing is being displayed on the screen. Its still the same, i.e., for some amount of time the screen freezes and then after a delay of like 2-3 seconds the information is loaded. Can you please advise as to where am I going wrong?

Comment: how are you loading the data, it sounds like you are synchronously loading the data (which would mean that though you show the mask, it is already hidden by the time the GUI is ready to do an update). In general javascript is single threaded, so long operations should be rewritten that they do not lock the GUI for an overly long period of time (like 2-3 seconds)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I have the data in a variable. I am just adding this data one by one to the store of the 2nd panel using a loop. You mentioned long operations should be rewritten so that they are not able to lock the GUI. Can you please provide some link or resource to help me understand various ways to rewrite code in such a way? In terms of efficiency there is no counter to adding the data row by row from this variable using a loop. Any other insight would be helpful

Comment: it is hard to suggest without seeing the code that loads the data, if you could show the code or a reconstruction of the code, that would be very helpfull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to first show your masking like the way you are doing:

```
var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getCmp('eventsPanel'), {
        msg:"Please wait..."
});
myMask.show();
```

Then make a delayed [task](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.util.DelayedTask)

```
var task = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function(){
    //your loading panel2 with heavy data goes here
    myMask.hide();
});
//start the task after 500 miliseconds
task.delay(500);
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: so, this would then show the busy indicator, block 2 - 3 seconds while his data loads, and busy indicator would be gone. But the blocking of the GUI would still happen with this delayed task, no?

Comment: The idea is to to make sure that the masking comes up on the screen, I have moved the heavy UI work in the delayed task. which will be triggred 500ms after the masking is come.
Once the masking is up there will not be any event handled and the single javascript thread is free to finish its heavy UI work.
Thus there will be no screen freezing.
Once the task is over remove the masking.

Comment: There will be screen freezing as soon as the heavy loading comes (even animated gifs would stand still), the only thing your solution is adding is that one actually sees the mask (and it will be moving for half a second). The real freezing won't be solved by using a DelayedTask imho.

Comment: @Icepickle the problem illustrated by aayush_v20 is that he does not see the mask screen while the heavy UI work is on the way.
The solution I offer is that he will **see the mask** while the delayed task runs. Definitely delayed task is no solution to freezing. To reduce teh freezing may be we need to look into the code for optimization.

Comment: My issue definitely was that I cannot see the freeze screen, but I wanted that because the data loading was taking time. This does help me show the mask, that's true. I also wished to know why my approach wasn't working and Icepickle provided an explanation for that. As for code optimization I have increased the efficiency and now the loading is quite quick. As such I do not require a mask :)

Comment: Thanks! It's very helpful when we don't have after load function

Answer (score 1):

I make a custom mask as follows:

```
var componentToMasK = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myChildComponent')[0];
var customMask = Ext.get(componentToMasK.getEl()).mask('My mask text...');

var task = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function() {

    customMask.fadeOut({
        duration : 500,
        remove:true
    });

});

task.delay(1000);
```

Normally when a event is triggered in a first component, caused, for example, the loading of a grid in the second component, the mask appears in both components in order to avoid user errors by clicking on the first component as the second component is loading the grid or is loading the mask.

In this case:

```
var componentToMasK = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myParentComponent')[0]; //HBox, BBox layout, tab, etc. with the two child components
```

Hope this helps!

Edit: 10-06-2015

The 'duration:500' and the 'delay(1000)' is only to illustrate. You can adjust these values to the needs of each component that you apply a mask.

If you remove the mask abruptly the user can not even see
loading the message, that's why I use fadeOut.

Thus, you can apply a mask on virtually any component such as, for example, a fieldset, when you add it fields dynamically.

task -> http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.util.DelayedTask

Ex.get -> http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext-method-get

fadeOut - > http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-fadeOut

You can also do the following:

```
var task = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function() {
   Ext.getBody().unmask();
});
task.delay(1000);
```

You can read more about this technique in the book: Mastering Ext JS - Second Edition (Loiane Groner)

Edit: 10-06-2015

One more detail:
If we apply one mask on a Hbox layout, containing as one of the childs a grid, we have two mask: HBOX mask and grid mask.
In these cases, I turn off dynamically the grid mask:

```
var grid =  Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#griditemId')[0];
if(grid){
     grid.getView().setLoading(false);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Can you provide some reference so that I can better understand this way of creating a custom mask because I am unable to understand clearly the working of this method. Does this set the timer of the mask to 500? That it will fade after this much amount of time?

Comment: A duration:500 e o delay(1000) é só para ilustrar. Voçê pode ajustar esses valores às necessidades de cada componente a que voçê aplica uma mask.

Comment: Não, eu queria perguntar o conceito por trás do desvanecimento . Será que os números representam a quantidade de tempo que leva antes a máscara está desbotada fora? Perdoe-me que eu não estou familiarizado com a sua língua , então eu estou usando Traduz Google para o mesmo.

Comment: Sorry for writing in Portuguese: my mistake.
I edited my answer.

Comment: I edited my answer to one more detail that can be useful